# Trying to write an algorithm that determines whether a string of parenthesis is valid

Tags: java, parentheses

I made a piece of code to check whether a string of parentheses was valid or not. my mindset was that I would count the opening parenthesis and put them in an array. after that, if there was a closing parenthesis I would replace the opening parenthesis in the array with something else like the letter A. after all of that was done I would check if all of the characters in the array were the letter A. This doesn't really seem efficient and I haven't gotten the code to work yet. I don't seem to be getting any syntax errors but I do seem to be getting a null pointer exception at line 26 of my code:

`if(!(arrays[i].equals("A")))`.

Heres: the entire piece of code to assess:

```
public class Parenth {
    public boolean validParentheses(String parens){
          int count=0;
        String[] arrays= new String[parens.length()];
          if(parens.substring(0,1).equals(")"))
             {
             return false;
             }
          for(int i=0;i<parens.length();i++)
            {
            if(parens.substring(i,i+1).equals("("))
              {
               arrays[count]= parens.substring(i,i+1);
               count++;
              }
            if(parens.substring(i,i+1).equals(")"))
              {
                arrays[count-1]= "A";
              }
             }
          for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++)
            {
            if(!(arrays[i].equals("A")))
                {
                  return false;
                }
            }
          return true;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Parenth a = new Parenth();
a.validParentheses("()()()()()");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered printing the `i` value and the contents inside the `array[i]` to see why the contents are `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a stack data structure:

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack();
char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '(') {
        stack.push(str[i]);
    } else {
        if (str[i] == ')') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') return false;
        }
    }
}
return stack.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score -2):

A much simpler option is to count all the opening brackets and all the closing brackets and check if they're the same value.

The only time this does not work is when the first bracket in the string is a closing one, so I caught that special case

```
public boolean validParentheses(String parens) {

    int firstClosingIndex = parens.indexOf(")");
    int firstOpeningIndex = parens.indexOf("(");
    if (firstClosingIndex < firstOpeningIndex && firstClosingIndex != -1) {
        return false;
    }

    int openingBrackets = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parens.length(); i++) {
        if (parens.charAt(i) == '(') {
            openingBrackets ++;
        }
    }

    int closingBrackets = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parens.length(); i++) {
        if (parens.charAt(i) == ')') {
            closingBrackets ++;
        }
    }
    
    return closingBrackets == openingBrackets;
}
```

Comment: What if it's `)(`? It's not a valid string of parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, I added an edge case for that

Comment: What if it's `())(`? It fails because now you are only checking for first 2 chars of the entire string of parenthesis. Usually, **Stack** data structure is used to check whether a string of parenthesis is valid or not.